# ASP.NET Core response compression not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an endpoint that loads a json from a file and then return its contents (ASP.NET Core 2.0):

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ReportsController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            string contentRootPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "reports");

            return Ok(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentRootPath + "\\teste.json"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, new ResponseError(ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

When hitting this endpoint in Chrome, I get the following network data:

[image]

Now if I enable response compression, the size of the request gets bigger:

[image]

Here's my `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        services.AddApplicationServices();

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(...);

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                ...
            });

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { ... });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            ...
        });

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Is any compression working at all - Static files for example?